# Is it possible to extend a partition with another partition blocking it?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, diskmanagement, gparted

I have an Ubuntu VM that I am trying to extend.  It is currently 20 GB total, with 19.12 being the main partition, with an 895 MB partition at the end.  I am trying to extend the large partition to be approximately 40 GB.

I have gotten VMWare to allocate the space, but it is currently just 20 GB of unallocated space at the end, directly after both partitions.  So, it is the large partition, the 895 MB partition, then 20 GB of unallocated space.

I have live booted into GParted, but I'm not sure how to extend the large partition by 20 GB, since the small partition is in between it and the unallocated space.  Is it possible to extend the large partition?

Answer (score 1):

With conventional partition tables, it is not possible to do directly as partitions have to be contiguous.  LVM has no problem with this, but you have to format the disk for LVM when you install, so that won't help you now.  At this point you can use gparted to move the partition that is in the way over, so that it is no longer in the way, THEN you can extend the first partition.

Comment: Right, this is what I mean.  Is there an easy way to move the partition that is in the way to the end?

Comment: @coffee yes, by using gparted, like I said...

Comment: Indeed.  In the question, I stated that I had already live booted with GParted, but I don't see how I can move the blocking partition to the end.  It won't let me move it to the right.  I can extend the blocking partition, but I don't appear to be able to move it

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new partition of 895M at the end of the disk
- copy your data over
- delete the blocking partition and then grow your partition to 40G.

You'll have to edit your fstab, so depending on what is on that 895M partition, you may need to have a live cd handy.

Comment: or use gparted livecd to automate it all for you, will take some time, especially in a vm

Comment: gparted livecd will automate this?  Hmm